# Angular ngOnChanges method

Tags: angular

I'm new in Angular and I have been studying component LifeHooks lately, and I dont really get one thing about `ngOnChanges`. Does it trigger only child components? If I use code like this

In `app.component.ts`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers: [Logger]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, DoCheck, AfterContentInit, AfterContentChecked, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    heroes = ['Windstorm', 'Bombasto', 'Magneta', 'Tornado'];
    myHero = this.heroes[0];
    hero: string;
    power: string;
```

And template like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="hero" placeholder="Hero name">
<input [(ngModel)]="power" placeholder="Hero power">

 <!--Using [] brackets can set property of COMPONENT or html ELEMENT-->
<app-on-changes [hero]="hero" [power]="power"></app-on-changes>
```

It triggers the child's `ngOnChanges` method but when I use input binding inside child's template - the method is not getting called.

In `on-changes.component.html`

```
<p>
  <input [(ngModel)]="hero" placeholder="Hero name">
  <input [(ngModel)]="power" placeholder="Hero power">
  
  {{hero}}  {{power}}
</p>
```

In `on-changes.component.ts`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-on-changes',
    templateUrl: './on-changes.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./on-changes.component.css'],
    providers: [Logger]
})
export class OnChangesComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input() hero: string;
    @Input() power: string;
    constructor(private logger: Logger) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        this.logger.log('OnChangeComponent changed properties');

        for (let propName in changes) {
            let chng = changes[propName];
            let cur  = JSON.stringify(chng.currentValue);
            let prev = JSON.stringify(chng.previousValue);
            this.logger.log(`${propName}: currentValue = ${cur}, previousValue = ${prev}`);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ngOnChanges()` is called when a parent component modifies (or initializes) the values bound to the input properties of a child. So if a component has no parent, the `ngOnChanges()` won't be invoked.

You are changing the values of the `@Input` properties using two-way binding, but this won't invoke `ngOnChanges()`.